# ffmpeg - How to scale a video then apply a watermark and scrolling text

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I have created a batch file for processing all my videos applied a watermark and scrolling text.

Here's the code:

`for %%a in ("original\HD\*.*") do  ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark-HD.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text='This video was uploaded to abc.com':fontfile=interface-bold.ttf:y=h-line_h-10:x=w-mod(max(t-3\,0)*(w+tw)/30\,(w+tw)):fontcolor=ffffff:fontsize=22:borderw=2:bordercolor=black [text]; [text][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause`

How can I scale videos to 480p at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a scale filter after the overlay,

```
[text][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=-2:480,setsar=1
```

or you can scale it beforehand,

```
[0:v]scale=-2:480,setsar=1,drawtext=text...
```

The setsar is to flag the pixels as square, so players don't try to stretch the video.